# How to create shape objects for Pane?

Tags: java, javafx

My project is creating a simple 2D ping pong game. I am using the Pane class, however I find it tedious to having to add the shape objects which I create to `root.getChildren().add()` method everytime. I am trying to create a function to do this but I do not know how I would call the method to add all the objects created to `root.getChildren().add()`

Code:

```
 package sample;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.paint.*;
import javafx.scene.shape.*;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.canvas.*;

public class Main extends Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        int SCREEN_WIDTH = 600;
        int SCREEN_HEIGHT = 600;

        //Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("sample.fxml"));
        Group root = new Group();
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT, Color.BLACK);

        Pane canvas = new Pane();
        canvas.setStyle("-fx-background-color: black;");
        canvas.setPrefSize(SCREEN_WIDTH,SCREEN_HEIGHT);
        //Rectangle rect1 = new Rectangle(200,50,Color.BLUE);

        root.getChildren().add(**drawShapes()**); // trying to call method


        primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public void drawShapes() { // function I am trying to implement
        Rectangle rect1 = new Rectangle(200,50,Color.BLUE);
    }

}
```

E.g. I am wanting to create a rectangle object and add it to the pane using the function to be displayed.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: work through a tutorial on java language basics ... in particular chapters on loops and passing parameters into a method.

Comment: See: [learning the java language](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/index.html), hopefully oracle's tutorial can help you.

Comment: `drawShapes` returns void. My guess is you need to return a `List` of `Shapes` and use `oot.getChildren().addAll(drawShapes());`

Answer (score 1):

You need to return your `Rectagle`, like

```
    public void drawShapes() { // function I am trying to implement
        return new Rectangle(200,50,Color.BLUE);
    }
```

Or you can delegate the whole thing:

```
public void drawShapes(Group root) { // function I am trying to implement
    root.getChildren().add(new Rectangle(200,50,Color.BLUE));
}
```

but then you will need to change the way you use `drawShapes` by replacing

```
root.getChildren().add(**drawShapes()**);
```

with

```
drawShapes(root);
```